# Can i use a .map() in a switch?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I need to make a code to choose among jobs, and I wanted to use a switch to do it. Using MongoDB and Mongoose I did a `.find()`, to get every job in the collection, and then I declared a `switch`. Since I didn't want to update the code every time I added or removed a job from the database, I thought about doing a `.map()` with the results of the `.find()` I did before.

And so I started writing some code, and I got a syntaxError. I'll paste the code so you can see what I did.

```js
const jobs = await jobModel.find()

switch (args[0]) {
   jobs.map((job) => {
      case job.jobname:
         console.log(job.jobname)
   })
   default:
      message.channel.send(fofEmbed)
      break;
}
```

Now here's my question, is there any way to have a map in a switch state? If not, how can I have a dynamic number of cases based on the jobs I have in the database?

Comment: No. That's invalid syntax. :)

Comment: So there's literally no way to have a dynamic switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can create a custom switch statement as shown below,

var callbackArr = [];
function customSwitch(casestmt, callback){
     var callbackObj = {};
     callbackObj['cs'] = casestmt;
     callbackObj['clbkfn'] = callback;
     callbackArr.push(callbackObj);
}
function switchExecute(condition) {
   const fn = callbackArr[callbackArr.findIndex(data => data.cs ===condition)].clbkfn(); 
}
jobs = [{'jobname': 'job1'},{'jobname': 'job2'}, {'jobname': 'job3'},{'jobname': 'job4'} ];
jobs.forEach((job)=> {
  customSwitch(job.jobname, ()=> {console.log(job.jobname)});
});

switchExecute(args[0]);
```

You can use closures to manage the scope of callbackArr.